# C/C++ - Simulate long running operation

Tags: c++, c, unix

I am analyzing a parallel algorithm running on multiple processors.

But it is a simple one, so I need to simulate a long running operation to analyze effective speedup.

1. sleep()/usleep() is not an option. I need to keep CPU busy, so that slave program can't work during times when other slaves sleep. Here speedup is incorrect.
2. Long empty for-loop is an option. But I also want to set the operation time explicitly.

Is there a way to combine these two or use something else to get time-fixed long operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`gettimeofday`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/gettimeofday.html) before entering the loop and remember the time. Within the loop, call [`gettimeofday`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/gettimeofday.html) continuously and calculate the difference between the current time and the beginning. When the difference is big enough, break out of the loop.

In essence, something like that:

```
struct timeval tv_begin, tv_current;
gettimeofday(&tv_begin, NULL);

for (;;) {
    gettimeofday(&tv_current, NULL);
    unsigned long long diff = 
        (tv_current.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv_current.tv_usec) -
        (tv_begin.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv_begin.tv_usec);

    if (diff > TIMEOUT)
        break;
}
```

Comment: But I guess it would be good to compute (tv_begin.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv_begin.tv_usec) once and maybe use some short for-loop inside to call gettimeofday more rarely.
My program actually runs on my PC on multiple cores, not CPUs. So I think calling gettimeofday from many slaves so often might be too hardcore.

Comment: You could do something like this with the realtime clock register - if your CPU has one - which won't load the system so badly.

Comment: what timeout here? is it milliseconds or seconds?

Answer (score 3):

[getitimer()/setitimer()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setitimer.2.html).  Set the timer, have the signal handler for SIGALRM set a switch that breaks you out of the loop.  The loop does what it does - or maybe nothing - until the timer goes off.

Comment: Thank you. I may try it as an option.

Comment: +1, this may be a better option as it doesn't issue a system call at each iteration, less context switching therefore.